How to calculate the expected value of the ratio of Gaussian random vectors?
Considering a complex Gaussian random vector $\boldsymbol h \sim {\mathcal{N}_\mathbb{C}}\left( {{\boldsymbol 0_N},{\sigma ^2}{\boldsymbol I_N}} \right)$ and a same dimensional complex vector $\boldsymbol a \in {\mathbb{C}^N}$, I was trying to calculate the following expectations,
$\mathbb{E}\left\{ {\tfrac{1}{{{{\left\| \boldsymbol h \right\|}^2}}}} \right\} = ?,\;\mathbb{E}\left\{ {\tfrac{{{\boldsymbol h^T}\boldsymbol a{\boldsymbol a^H}{\boldsymbol h^*}}}{{{{\left\| \boldsymbol h \right\|}^2}}}} \right\} = ?,\;\mathbb{E}\left\{ {\tfrac{{{\boldsymbol h^T}\boldsymbol a{\boldsymbol a^H}{\boldsymbol h^*}}}{{{{\left\| \boldsymbol h \right\|}^4}}}} \right\} = ?$
Previous works have demonstrated that we can use the approximation method to calculate the last two terms, i.e., $\mathbb{E}\left\{ {\tfrac{x}{y}} \right\} = \tfrac{{\mathbb{E}\left\{ x \right\}}}{{\mathbb{E}\left\{ y \right\}}}$, however, this method provides less accuracy when the vector dimension $N$ is small.
I would like to inquire if there exists any research that addresses these issues. Thanks.
